# add link to image in javascript core

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink, href

I need to add a link to an image in javascript but I don't know how to!!
you can see [my codes here](http://jsfiddle.net/mansiz/wa5609rc/).

this code is for changing an image (a1) and show image (a2) instead of that.
I like to add my website address to image "a2".

some thing like this but in JS:

```
<a href="http://site-2.url/" class="leftlink sitelink">
  <img src="http://uupload.ir/files/gvmb_b1.png" alt="alt-2" title="title-2">
</a>
```

.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#ftr .specialFtr img');
for (var i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i++) {
  images[i].src = 'http://uupload.ir/files/mia_a2.png';
}
```

what should I add to it?
(I know nothing about javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `i` inside the loop in the assigned url value:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#ftr .specialFtr img');
for (var i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i++) {
  images[i].src = 'http://uupload.ir/files/bmtq_a' + i + '.png';
  console.log(images[i].src);
}
```

```html
<div id="ftr">
  <div class="specialFtr">
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
```